# How to return a stream based on another stream's event

Tags: dart, stream, dart-async

I want to return a stream based on another stream's value/event.

For example, if I have a 2 streams, stream1 and stream2, I want to create a function which returns as stream either stream2 or null, depending on the value of stream1. How can I do that?

I tried to map stream1 and based on the event to yield stream2, but it does not work. I also can't listen to stream1 and based on the event yield stream2.

```
Stream<Data1?> getStream1() async* {
  // yield stream1
}

Stream<Data2?> getStream2(dynamic value) async* {
  //yield stream2 based on value
}

Stream<Data2?> getStream12() async* {
  final stream1 = getStream1();
  // not working
  yield* stream1.map((event) => event == null ? null : getStream2(event.var));
  // I also tried await for, but it has a strange behaviour
  // if I listen to the stream after (it's inconsistent)
  await for (var event in stream1) {
    if (event == null) {
      yield null;
    } else {
      yield* getStream2(event.var);
    } 
  }
}
```

Is there any solution to this, preferable without any additional package dependencies like rxdart, just pure dart?

Comment: Your `await for` code looks correct. What isn't working for you? What errors do you get?

Comment: @Irn First time I run it, it works, then it stops working. Like, let's say I put in `stream1: value1 -> null -> value2`, `getStream12()` changes for `value1`, then for `null`, then it does not change again for `value2`.

Comment: That sounds more like a problem with `getStream2` than with the `await for` loop. Try checking that `getStream2` doesn't cache or reuse something between calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `await for` have to work...

Can you try this?

```dart
Stream<int> getStream1() async* {
  yield 1;
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  yield null;
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  yield 2;
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
}

Stream<int> getStream2(dynamic value) async* {
  yield value;
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  yield value;
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
}

Stream<int> getStream12() {
  return getStream1().asyncExpand(
    (event) => event == null ? Stream.value(null) : getStream2(event),
  );
}

void main() {
  getStream12().listen(print);
}
```

Output:

```
1
1
null
2
2
```

Comment: This is working, indeed.

Comment: Thank you for checking this out. @Ghost